# Call two or more functions one after another

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I want to call two or more methods after another. When One function execution get's completed I need to call another method.  Basically I am trying to implement the backup functionality in my app. I am developing **Windows Phone** app which take backup of contacts, images, video. I have created the method for each of these. When backup of contacts is completed then I want to call images method. I have created different functions for these. How can I call these function one after another?

I have tried something like this.

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UploadImagesThread = new Thread(UploadImages);
        UploadContactsThread = new Thread(UploadContacts);
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
```

On Upload **button click**

```
 if (chkContacts.IsChecked.Value)
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
         SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Searching contacts...";
     });
     UploadContactsThread.Start();
 }
 if (chkImages.IsChecked.Value)
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
          SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Compressing images...";
     });
     UploadImagesThread.Start();
 }
```

But It will not help me. How do I emplement? My **UploadContact** method has **Async** method call like this

```
Contacts objContacts = new Contacts();
objContacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(objContacts_SearchCompleted);
objContacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Tasks, which will let you give you a thread pool for free. You can't do this in a constructor but you could override you OnNavigatedTo Mehtod:

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        await Task.Run(() => { UploadImages(); });
        await Task.Run(() => { UploadContacts(); });
    }
```

The await will ensure that the contacts will start uploading after your images are completed. You could also check out [background uploading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which means your app will not have to run while the action is completing.

Comment: It gives me an error `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'`

Comment: @AjayPunekar Sorry my bad updated my anser. I'm guessing that UploadImages has got the Signature with return type task?

Comment: Both method have return type `void`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Task.ContinueWith()` to chain up the calls.

You can have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx.

Applied to your problem, this should do the trick:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(UploadImages).ContinueWith(UploadContacts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem (call one method after another?) is not very clear, but looking at your code, I suppose you want to wait for the `UploadImagesThread` thread to complete before starting the `UploadContactsThread`.

Use tasks and the async/await keywords like this:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, ...)
{
  if (chkContacts.IsChecked.Value)
  {
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Searching contacts...";
      await Task.Run(() => UploadImages());
  }
  if (chkImages.IsChecked.Value)
  {
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Compressing images...";
      await Task.Run(() => UploadContacts());
  }
}
```

Note: assuming your 2nd block of code is running on the UI thread, you shouldn't need to use `BeginInvoke`.

---

**Edit**

In response to your recent changes: you need a redesign. Try this:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, ...)
{
  bool uploadContacts = chkContacts.IsChecked.Value;
  bool uploadImages = chkImages.IsChecked.Value;

  //use this if the continuation runs on the UI thread
  Action continuation = async () => {
    if(uploadImages) {
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Compressing images...";
      await Task.Run(() => UploadImages());
    }
  };

  //OR this if it doesn't
  Action continuation = () => {
    if(uploadImages) {
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Compressing images...");
      UploadImages();
    }
  };

  if (uploadContacts)
  {
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Searching contacts...";
      UploadContacts(continuation);
  }
}

private void UploadContacts(Action continuation)
{
  Contacts objContacts = new Contacts();

  //when the search has finished, trigger your event handler AND the continuation task, which will upload the images
  objContacts.SearchCompleted += objContacts_SearchCompleted;
  objContacts.SearchCompleted += (sender, args) => continuation();

  objContacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'`

Comment: It gives me error `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`. The function return type is void.

Comment: @AjayPunekar on which line? what's the signature of `UploadImages` and `UploadContacts`?

Comment: Return type of this function is `void`

Comment: @AjayPunekar On which line do you get the `Only assignment, call...` error?

Comment: On `await Task.Run(() => UploadContacts);`

Comment: @AjayPunekar My bad, fixed it! Try once more please

Comment: It working fine. But the problem is in my UploadContact method. check my uploadcontact method in question. It has SearchAsync method. because of this method `uploadImagemethod` is calling. Before completing the task of UploadContact method

Comment: @AjayPunekar You need to redesign this. Take a look at my new answer.

Comment: It gives me two error `Cannot await 'void'` and second is `The name 'async' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @AjayPunekar Updated again. I wrote two `Action`s. Try both, see which one does not block the UI thread.

Comment: I got two error on this line `Action continuation = () {` 1st is `) expected` and 2nd is `Invalid expression term ')'`

Comment: @AjayPunekar I forgot about the `=>`

Comment: Ok wait i will try to run this.

Comment: What exactly is the issue again? Is there any more code in `UploadContacts` besides the code you posted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48467/discussion-between-dcastro-and-ajay-punekar)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
        bool backContact = chkContacts.IsChecked.Value;
        bool backImages = chkImages.IsChecked.Value;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        if (backContact) {
                            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Searching contacts...";
                            });
                            UploadContacts;
                        });
                    }).ContinueWith(() =>
                        {
                            if (backImages) {
                                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Compressing images...";
                            });
                            UploadImages;
                            }
                        }
```